# HTML headings are considered as clickable by NVDA

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, accessibility, nvda

The context is that we want to track user behavior of application for it's different features.

For this we have created a custom angular directive say     *myFunctionality*
and wrapped portions of HTML into this directive like this, so that now we can **track all click events within** this, and categorize them by *functionality-name* to track the usage of a particular feature -

```
<myFunctionality functionality-name="Login">
 <!--HTML of this functionality-->
</myFunctionality>

<myFunctionality functionality-name="RegisterUser">
 <!--HTML of this functionality-->
</myFunctionality>
```

Within this directive, we have attached event handler to capture `click` event and log accordingly.

```
.directive('myFeature', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            //more code

            element.on('click.myFeature', '*:not(select, :radio, :checkbox)', function(event) {
                logEventDetails(event);
            });

            //more code

        }])
```

This is working, beautifully, except that when I read my page using `NVDA` screen reader.
NVDA reads the `heading` elements as clickable.
For example for this heading -

```
<h1> Test Heading </h1>
```

NVDA reads:

> Test Heading heading clickable level 1

I have also tried using something like this, *(with variety of versions)* but it did not worked-

```
$(':header').off('click.myFeature');
```

**TL;DR**

Consider the following sample HTML. Here `click` is associated with `div` and not with `h1`. But screen reader works such that it reads heading element also as clickable.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div onclick="alert('Hello from Div!')">
        <h1>Test Heading</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can prevent NVDA from reading non-clickable events as clickable?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> <div onclick="alert('Hello from Div!')">
>     <h1>Test Heading</h1>
> </div>
> ```
>
> How can prevent NVDA from reading non-clickable events as clickable?

Your heading is clickable, because it's inside a clickable element.

Just put it outside any clickable element.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, yeah, I think this is how it works, and we have little control over it. I was anticipating it to be read as non-clickable, when click is there in parent element :(. For application design, we are not able to change the positioning of controls.

Comment: I've encountered the same issue on a project that uses Adobe Dynamic Tag Management (DTM), which dynamically tags various elements with `onlick` for analytics, and can also attest that if you put `tabindex="-1"` on a _semantic tag_, you will also hear NVDA announce "clickable". You can [read a discussion about this on the NVDA issues](https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/5481#issuecomment-241574110), which one of the main developers explains the behavior. I also have an opened issue with NVDA at https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/6639